# Blank space on the right and cannot figure out what caused it

Tags: css, wordpress

I have trying to make this site adaptive (not responsive), but for the life of me, I cannot make the blank space on the right disappear on mobile. I have tried all kinds of viewport, and also changing the width of containers, menu, and body width.

I can see that the menu is sticking out, but there is a part on the right of the menu that is blank:

[image: Screenshot]

URL: barbican.metricdesign.net

Comment: It would be helpful if you can please attach the screenshot of the blank space you are talking about.

Comment: your site is not responsive that why your footer make the site scrolled and create the issue , footer is larger in size. check and make the footer responsive along with full site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `container` div inside your header to 100% width and your `side-footer` width to 100% also. You have a `min-width` applied to both these items, along with a defined width of 1040px px on your header container. This is causing your page to scroll horizontally as it shrinks past 1040px, which creates the white space you see.

```
.container {
   width:100%;
}

.side-footer {
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! this worked!!! I had missed the .side-footer part of the solution before.